# How can I set cookies in a Django middleware?

Tags: django, cookies, middleware

I tried several version of this:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):

    if not request.COOKIES.get('new_user', None):

        print "cookie"

        max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  # 10 years
        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age)
        response.set_cookie('new_user', expires=expires)


    return response
```

But it doesn't work: I get "cookie" printed at every page request, and no cookie is appearing in my FF dev toolbar cookie lister. I didn't set any of my browser to reject cookies.

I'm currently using the developpement server and I do have the common and session middlewares set as the first ones in settings. I don't have any cookie settings set.

Answer (score 5):

After hours searching, I discovered that you have to set the `max_age` parameter:

```
response.set_cookie('ref', request.GET.get('ref', ''),
                    expires=expires.utctimetuple(), max_age=max_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie):

> expires should either be a string in the format **"Wdy, DD-Mon-YY
>   HH:MM:SS GMT"** or a **datetime.datetime object in UTC**. If expires
>   is a datetime object, the max_age will be calculated.

So, try it:

```
>> import datetime
>>max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  # 10 years
>>expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age)

# Cookie to GMT format via strftime method
>>response.set_cookie('new_user', expires=expires.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT"))
```

or

```
>> response.set_cookie('new_user', expires=expires.utctimetuple())
```

I prefer the first method.

Comment: I do pass a datetime object dude.

Comment: Trie to supply socond numbers to max_age argument instead of expires parameter.

Comment: It's the same if I provide max_age.