# Tracking Django sessions with custom cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am looking for a way to track the time users spend on the site. I have found the package [django-tracking2](https://github.com/bruth/django-tracking2), which tracks visitors by the Django session. However, my session expiry is set to 2 weeks, which makes it useless to track daily activity. My thoughts are that I can create a different cookie that expires every day, so that I can use this cookie for tracking. However, I do not quite understand how exactly I would assign a random cookie every day for users, as the Django docs does not quite have examples on this.

The desired logic is:

1. When a user opens the app, check if cookie `custom_cookie` is set
2. If not, create it with a random value (probably uuid4?)
3. The cookie should expire the same day at midnight

I have come across this way of creating cookies in the middleware, however I think it will yield different random values in the request and response objects:

```py
class MyCookieProcessingMiddleware(object):

    # your desired cookie will be available in every django view
    def process_request(self, request):
        # will only add cookie if request does not have it already
        if not request.COOKIES.get('custom_cookie'):
            request.COOKIES['custom_cookie'] = uuid.uuid4()

    # your desired cookie will be available in every HttpResponse parser like browser but not in django view
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if not request.COOKIES.get('custom_cookie'):
            response.set_cookie('custom_cookie', uuid.uuid4())
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to generate only 24 hours or x duration token and don't want precise time**

[Use JWT token](https://jwt.io/)

You can also generate refresh tokens but it's lifespan is too short.

**To track precise time**

What you can do is create your random value and separate it with . (dot)
After dot you should add current time and then again a . (dot) after this dot you will add end time. This will be your cookie.

For example - "qwerty1234567890-=.10:03:04.00:00:00"

This would be in case if you want cookies to expire by EOD

In above string
**qwerty1234567890-=** is uuid
**10:03:04** is start time
**00:00:00** is end time
separated by **DOT (.)**

You can also change the end time based on time delta (of python)
For example -

```
ini_time_for_now = datetime.now()
future_date_after_24hours = ini_time_for_now + \ timedelta(hours = 24)
future_date_after_24hours =future_date_after_24hours.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(future_date_after_24hours)
```

So to track precise time what you will do is create a column precise_time in your database. You will track precise time by below method.

First user will visit your page then token will get generated with start time and end time.

It will get stored in form of cookies in his browser

next time he visits page again, you will check end time == current time (you can use split())
if not then start time - end time

[To find time difference in integer value](https://pynative.com/python-get-time-difference/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20time%20difference,total_seconds()%20methods.&text=Multiply%20the%20total%20seconds%20by,the%20time%20difference%20in%20milliseconds.&text=Divide%20the%20seconds%20by%2060%20to%20get%20the%20difference%20in%20minutes.)

Now you will store that time to database

You will keep on repeating this process until current time == end time. If this will be the case then set new cookie.

You can also add username to the cookie string to uniquely identify the user.
My concept is based on JWT token.

**Custom based cookies**

You can follow above method just remove start time and add only end time. If current time == end time, generate a new token with end time and update it.

Comment: Seems like this could be a possibility for me, however, I am more confused about actually saving and reading the cookie in the django middleware.

Comment: ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885221/how-can-i-set-cookies-in-a-django-middleware )  I think so this will help you